# JSF navigation rules causing problems

Tags: jsf-2

I have a certain method verifying the user role and permission returning a boolean on the managed bean, when read by the JSF page, I get this message:

```
Sept. 25, 2015 4:54:29 PM com.sun.faces.application.resource.ResourceHandlerImpl logMissingResource
WARNING: JSF1064: Unable to locate or use a resource, /module/usermanager/backend/true.xhtml.
```

While the true is the result from the method and that renders a certain viewAction or any component like this

```
<f:viewAction action="#{userloginMB.verifyPermission(2,5,2)}" />
<p:column style="width:20%" rendered="#userloginMB.verifyPermission(1,2,2)==true}">
```

Is there a way to make not consider returned vars as a redirection?

Comment: What are you trying to do with `<f:viewAction>` in first place?

Comment: That verifies if the user has the primitive permission of viewing the page

Comment: Those two rendered are just a sample not in same place neither in same page

Comment: Why exactly are you returning `true` as navigation outcome? What exactly did you expect when it returns `false`? It should instead return the view you'd like to navigate to.

Comment: It means user is permitted to see that part of page otherwise it returns false and its not rendered

Comment: There is the `<f:viewAction>` not for. You should return `null` if you want to stay on same view, else return a valid view ID where you'd like to redirect to.

Comment: Okey and for the other component ? It needs a returned value to render

Comment: It will always evaluate true because the value is not interpreted as an EL expression, but as a literal string which is not null nor empty.

Comment: Thank you. Yout guideline helped me as i separated the method into one to verify if user logged in with a method returning a void and another for components returing a boolean and xith this i get no more messages. Thank you